# Table as a footnote in LaTeX (LEd + MikTex 2.8 + Windows XP)

Tags: latex, footnotes

I want to place a small 4x4 table as a footnote in a manuscript that I am preparing for an IEEE Journal. Has any one tried this before? How to do it? I haven't got any leads yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For questions about LaTeX, you will get better answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/. I'm flagging this question for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the "standard approach" work?

```
\footnote{My table: \begin{tabular}{cc} A & B \\ C & D \end{tabular}}
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo.
\begin{table}...\end{table} does not work.
This is what one of my friend explained
"It creates a bounded frame for encapsulation of contents. Since Footnote is a floating encapsulation environment, so they conflict and the document properties fail to identify precedence thus resulting of non-compilation of following commands and loss of interpretation of \end{document}"

Comment: Please note the difference between table and tabular here :-)